# Login system using Firebase showing user doesn't exist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i hard code 2 users in firebase database and then code to check its working . i login with user ID that is contact number. every time it returns `User not exists in database` instead of showing `sign in successfully`. i have attached `signIN.java` code and `Firebase` image.

```
    EditText edtPhone, edtPassword;
    Button btnSignIn;


        edtPassword=(MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
        edtPhone= (MaterialEditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
        btnSignIn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignIn.this);
                mDialog.setMessage("Please Waiting...");
                table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //check if user not in database
                        if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

                            // getting user info
                            mDialog.show();
                            User user = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                            if (user.getPassword().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign in Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Sign in failed!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "User not exists in database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

database

[image]

User class code
`

```
private String Name;

private String Password;

public User(String name, String password) {
    Name = name;
    Password = password;
}
public User(){

}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return Password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    Password = password;
}
```

}
`

Comment: Why aren't you using Firebase Signin libraries? Storing passwords in plain text is not secure

Comment: Anyways, you're ignoring all errors in onCancelled, and you might want to consider matching the string case of the database at `getReference("User")`... Can you please show your User class?

Comment: many thanks for your review. i am just cheking if firebase gives responce correctly or not i will use libraries later.it seems no issue with my codewhy firebase is not responding. kindly mention libraries name i will read about them .

Comment: yes sure i will edit in my question above.

Comment: I would suggest adding `Log.d("pass", user.getPassword())` in the code to check that. Then https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth

Comment: will you please explain it where i can add this line of code `Log.d("pass", user.getPassword())` ?

Comment: After you get a user and before you check the password ideally

Comment: thanks for pushing me up to debug errors. :)

Comment: but still cannot resolve my issue :(

Comment: Well, what got printed in the logcat?

Comment: do not support AFT because of no config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this

```
final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");
```

to -

```
final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("user");
```

I mean document should be in small case 'user'.